# Difference of two compact sets is compact

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

Consider this question:

> Let $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ be compact sets. Define $A=\{||x_{1}-x_{2}||:x_{1} \in K_{1}, x_{2} \in K_{2}\}$. Show that $A$ is compact.

My atempt consist in prove that $A$ is compact using the notion of sequentially compact.

$\textbf{My answer}$: Let $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ be compact sets. Therefore, every sequence has convergent subsequence. Consider the sequences $(x_{n}^{1})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in K_{1}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $(x_{n}^{2})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in K_{2}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence, $\exists (x_{n_{j}}^{1})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in K_{1}:x_{n_{j}}^{1} \to x^{1}$, and $\exists (x_{n_{j}}^{2})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in K_{2}:x_{n_{j}}^{2} \to x^{2}$. Since both $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ are compact sets, $x^{1} \in K_{1}$ and $x^{2} \in K_{2}$.

Therefore, the sequence defined as $y_{n}=x_{n_{j}}^{1}-x_{n_{j}}^{2} \to (x^{1}-x^{2}) \in A$, hence, $A$ is compact.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Just as advice: Throw away the $\forall$ and $\exists$ and use words more, it makes the proof look easier to digest (After all, we are here to look for your *argument*).

Comment: Yes. It's fine.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is alright, but you should define $y_{n}=x_{n}^{1}-x_{n}^{2}$, which has a subsequence of the form $y_{n_{j}}=x_{n_{j}}^{1}-x_{n_{j}}^{2}$, which, in turn, converges to $x_{1}-x_{2}$. Since a set is compact iff every sequence contained in the set has a convergent subsequence, $A$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : let $S_1,S_2$ are compact sets .$g,f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n, f(x,y) = x+y$,$g(x,y)=xy$ are continuous and so

$S_1 + S_2 = f[S_1 \times S_2]$.

$S_1 \times S_2$ is compact by Tychonoff , and if $S$ is compact so $-S$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think I'm supposed to prove this question by using Tychonoff, it's either using open covers or using some of the equivalences for compact sets in metric spaces. Do you have any feedback for what I've done?